# Window Service to Client Communication via SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, client-server

I am using Window Service as server to send data to window application as client.
I want to secure its communication via SSL encryption.
Bad luck in finding any guide to do this.

Anyone have idea about implement client server secure communication via ssl in window service please tell me.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: No solution found for this, we use encyption and decryption for security of data.